# Как сделать широкий график с горизонтальной прокруткой?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

Нужно сделать широкий временной график со статусами состояний и тд. Пока больше чем экран сделать не смог.
использовал

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(100,10))
```

или

```
fig.set_size_inches([100, 8])
```

Хотел бы что бы внизу была горизонтальная прокрутка, а сам график был очень широким. Так же хотелось бы графики находили друг под другом, и была и вертикальная прокрутка.
Сейчас мой код выглядит так:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(100,10))
#fig.set_size_inches([100, 8])

x = np.arange(1000)
for i in range(1, 23):
    ax = fig.add_subplot(23,1,i)
    y = np.random.random(1000)*100 - i * 200
    ax.plot(x,y)
    ax.grid(True)
plt.show()
```

Мне Andrio Skur помог решить вопрос с горизонтальной прокруткой. Осталась вертикальная. Нужно разместить 23 графика друг под другом. Если без прокруток, то графики очень невысокие получаются.
[image: результат кода]

Comment: Чем это не подходит http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31001713/plotting-the-data-with-scrollable-x-time-horizontal-axis-on-linux , http://scipy-cookbook.readthedocs.io/items/Matplotlib_ScrollingPlot.html ?

Comment: спасибо, только начал думать о таком же исполнении... но графиков много... возможно будет тормозить... а так, сейчас  попробую так реализовать! СПАСИБО!!! PS как тебе кармы подбросить?

Comment: @KtoTo, по поводу кармы: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/200092/andrio-skur?tab=answers выбрать хорошие ответы и отметить их как полезные... ;-)